# Piping nothing to xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a script that may in some circumstances have nothing on stdout. At the end of the script, I pass the lines I have to another command using xargs. My problem is, when there is nothing on stdout, I get the typical "Usage: program arg1 arg2" error message.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need an `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` options.

Keep in mind that this particular behavior is hard to make cross-platform.
BSD versions of `xargs` run with `-r` by default. GNU version needs it. FreeBSD version of `xargs` ignores `-r` flag for compatibility with GNU. Mac OS X version does not even accept the flag and throws an error `illegal option`.

You might then choose to use an OS detection based on `$OSTYPE` to write a cross-platform script.
Even better, try to detect the behavior of `xargs` itself. Run it with `-r` and if that fails (status code > 0), run it without `-r`.

Comment: Recent versions of macOS do allow `-r` for compatibility with GNU xargs. FreeBSD `xargs` skips the command by default with no input, so the flag doesn't change behavior on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

A lesson in why you should read the man pages…

The `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` flags are my friend.